# Find words with 3 consecutive consonants except specific combinations

Tags: regex, string

I have a large list of words and I want to select (filter) those words that have 3 or more consecutive consonants, except some specific combinations.

For example:

```
...
ikxzop
contribution
...
```

In that list I want to select the word `ikxzop` (it has `kxz`) but not `contribution` (it has `ntr`).

I was trying something like this:

```
 \w*[^aeiou]{3,}\w*\n
```

But that also select the word `contribution` and I don't know how to omit the `ntr` combination (and others common combination as `mpl`, `bst` or `rpr`).

Regards.

Comment: What are you doing? Extracting valid English words? Use an NLP package, it is no job for a regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew something like that, but simpler. Besides, this help me to learn more about RE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
\w*(?!ntr)(?!bst)(?!mpl)(?!rpr)[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]{3,}\w*
```

Will match any words containing *atleast three consecutive constants* which should be other than `ntr` or `bst` or `mpl` etc as defined.

- `[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]` denotes constants instead of `[^aeiou]` because the later allows line terminators, symbols etc. as well
- `(?!ntr)` Negative lookahead to ensure that `ntr` shouldn't be the three consecutive constants.

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/asfcTY/2/)

Matches `ikxzop`

Doesn't match `contribution`

Note that it will match a string such as `ntrd` although it contains `ntr` because there is an alternate 3 consecutive constants `trd` which is acceptable

Comment: The lookaheads in this situation won't help in all situations, good you noted it at the end.

Comment: Thanks, man! I didn't know that `[^aeiou]` allows symbols. Good to know.

Comment: Yes @WiktorStribiżew valid point - If `ntrd` is also to be rejected then lookaheads won't work here. Hence I made the assumption